# Card Flip animation in Libgdx

Tags: 3d, libgdx, flip

How i achieve the  card flip animation in Libgdx (flip at some angle)– 
i used **sprite.flip(boolean x, boolean y)** but unable to achieve the desired result.

I want to do similar to this :

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Comment: sprite.flip won't help you in this scenario, you can make two mesh planes and rotate them along x-axis to achieve this animation

Comment: @whiteFang thanks for the reply.. please give me some reference or link that help me to do this(i never used mesh plane)

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) in your code, you can use these two Actions I wrote:

```
public class MyActions {
    public static Action flipOut(final float x, final float width, final float duration) {
        return new Action() {
            float left = duration;

            @Override
            public boolean act(float delta) {
                left -= delta;
                if (left <= 0) {
                    actor.setX(x + (width / 2));
                    actor.setWidth(0);
                    return true;
                }
                float tmpWidth = width * (left / duration);
                actor.setX(x + ((width / 2) - (tmpWidth / 2)));
                actor.setWidth(tmpWidth);
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    public static Action flipIn(final float x, final float width, final float duration) {
        return new Action() {
            float done = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean act(float delta) {
                done += delta;
                if (done >= duration) {
                    actor.setX(x);
                    actor.setWidth(width);
                    return true;
                }
                float tmpWidth = width * (done / duration);
                actor.setX(x + ((width / 2) - (tmpWidth / 2)));
                actor.setWidth(tmpWidth);
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can combine those actions with

```
myActor.addAction(
    new SequenceAction(
        MyActions.flipOut(x, width, duration),
        MyActions.flipIn(x, width, duration)));
```

If you want your card to have different sides you would have to put in a middle action to switch the image of the actor.

You can also use inbuilt actions, this results in a lot of stuttering though, so I can't really recommend it:

```
SequenceAction action = new SequenceAction(
    new ParallelAction(
        Actions.scaleTo(0, 1, duration), 
        Actions.moveBy(width / 2, 0, duration)),
    new ParallelAction(
        Actions.scaleTo(1, 1, duration), 
        Actions.moveBy(-width / 2, 0, duration)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Shrink the width of the first picture until it's width is zero, then start increasing the width of the second image. For example:

```
    public void flip() {
        if(Graphic1.getWidth() == 0) {
             Graphic2.setWidth(Graphic2.getWidth()+5);
        } else {
             Graphic1.setWidth(Graphic1.getWidth()-5);
        }
    }
```

Call the `flip()` method in the `render()` method, with an `if()` statment detecting if the button has been pressed. Something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void render() { 
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        boolean ButtonPressed = false;

        if(ButtonPressed) { 
            flip(); 
        } 

    }
```

Activate `ButtonPressed` with the eventHandler for your button. Set it equal to `true`. Also, make sure that unless your button's eventHandler is in the `render()` method, you make `ButtonPressed` a static variable outside any methods, still inside the class.

```
    public class Demo {

        static boolean ButtonPressed = false;

        public void onCreate() {
        ...
```

If you wanted to create an even cooler effect, increase the distance at which the width shrinks each time the `flip()` method is called, then once the width is zero, start decreasing the amount each time.

Hope this helps!